# ember-cli get reference model in afterModel

Tags: ember.js

In my routes I have this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
        model:function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('book',params.id);
  },

  afterModel: function(model) {
      var title = model.get('title');
      var username = model.get('user').get('name');
$(document).attr('title', 'This '+ book + ' is belongs to '+ username);
        },
});
```

Model User and Model Book are reference with each other by 
In Book Model:

```
title: DS.attr('string'),
user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
```

When I play console.log(title): It show exactly what I want 
However with console.log(username): nah, it gets nothing..

I need helps to fix this right ..

Comment: I don't understand, so you are saying that `model.get('user').get('name');` is empty? If so, can you try doing `model.get('user.name');`. If that doesn't work. Try checking if the user model is present from the ember debugger.

Comment: @Charizard_ : console.log(model.get('user')); return a null class. And yes I can see 'user' model present in ember debug.

Comment: Then there should be an issue with the data returned by the `this.store.findRecord('book',params.id)`. Can you post that?

Comment: I am doing similar like this http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/28/setting-the-document-title-in-ember-apps.html . However, they are using get('attr') only inside the model ( artistname and songs are in same model ), Mine are at different model ..

Comment: Yes I use exactly what you said and in templates I can call {{model.user.username}}

model:function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('book',params.id);
  },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is while getting the `user` association, it actually returns a promise. So, try changing your `afterModel` hook to something like this.

```
  afterModel: function(model) {
      var title = model.get('title');
      model.get('user').then(function(user){
        var userName = user.get('name');
        $(document).attr('title', 'This '+ book + ' is belongs to '+ userName);
      });
  },
```

**EDIT:**
Using `model.user.username` would work in templates because the bindings are automagically resolved in templates when the promises get resolved. But in javascript, you need to wait for the promise to get resolved.

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you :D

Comment: Using `model.user.username` would work in templates because the bindings are automagically resolved in templates when the promises get resolved. But in javascript, you need to wait for the promise to get resolved.